# File in use when it's really not

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, windows-server-2008

I am running Windows 7 Professional 32 bit on a Server 2008 network. I am getting a weird issue with an excel document where I open it up one morning, update it, save and close, the next morning I come in, open it up and it says "This file is in use and locked by csmith" which "csmith" is me! So I click on the cancel button, open it up again and it comes up fine. I can edit, save and close with no problem. But then have the same issue the next morning.

Another weird thing is that we have a calendar shared in "Public Folders" under Outlook that seems to be having the same issue, which happens to be a calendar made in Excel. Exchange 2010 is installed on the server and the clients are using Exchange 2007. In the instance with the calendar, it will show conflicting edits have been made and you must keep one item or all items. And it shows an edit date of 4/24/2012 and 6/1/2012. But, there were NO edits done on 6/1, just tried opening it. This problem does not occur under my profile, but 2 others. These machines are ALSO running Windows 7 Professional 32 bit. We have a mix of Windows 7 and Windows XP machines on our network if that is any help.

These issues did not start happening until we migrated from a server running Server 2003 and Exchange 2000, which the new server is running Server 2008 and Exchange 2010 as stated above. Is there something on the server side that is configured wrong?

Comment: Process explorer (which can be downloaded from Microsoft's website) has a "search handles" feature. When the file is locked, search for the filename using this feature. It should tell you which process has it open. Though this might not show anything because it sounds like the server is locking it (presumably you are restarting the computer in the AM).

Comment: Actually, I'm not restarting the computer. Before I leave for the day I usually just lock it, instead of logging off or doing a restart.

Comment: OK, this might help point you in the right direction. Process Explorer also allows you to "kill" the file handle, releasing the lock, but this can cause stability issues. One thing I am suspicious about it that excel can run macros and it may be leaving a process open. Another obvious (and harmless) possibility is that windows explorer is holding the handle open. It does this in some circumstances (most often in my case thumbs.db--a hidden file--prevents a folder from being removed)

Comment: Disable thumbnailing, see if that cures it.

Comment: is the anti-virus or backup setup the same as before? Either might cause this.

Comment: If at some point excel was closed unexpectedly there might be some temporary hidden file with a name like `~$filename.xlsx`, with excel closed you can delete it and try again. See if that fixes it